# Distance from center of sphere to apex of pyramid?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d

A sphere of radius 1 sits inside a container shaped as an inverted pyramid. The top of the pyramid is a square that is horizontal, and the other faces are equilateral triangles.

[image]

Comment: Is the sphere in contact with any of the sides of the pyramid? If so please specify beforehand. because the diagram does not seem so.

Comment: What is the length of each side of the square?

Comment: By the "apex" of the pyramid, did you mean $A$? And the sphere touches all the pyramid's edges except possibly the square top, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the sphere is of radius 1.

Place the sphere at $(0,0,1)$

Place the vertices at $(k,0,0), (0,k,0), (0,0,k), (-k,0,0), (0,-k,0)$

I have turned it upside down, it is easier for me to visualize this way.

Find $k$ such that the sphere is tangent to the pyramid.

One of the faces is described by the plane $x + y + z - k = 0$

The point $(0,0,1)$ is one unit from the plane.

$\frac {k-1}{\sqrt 3}  = 1$

$k = \sqrt 3 + 1$

The distance from $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,k) = \sqrt 3$ units.

For a sphere of radius $r$ the distance is $r\sqrt 3$

Answer (score 0):

Let the square base be $BCDE$. Let $F,G$ respectively be the mid-point of $BC$ and $DE$.

Consider the cross-section containing triangle $AFG$. The triangle $AFG$ is equilateral, and a circle of radius $1$ which is a great circle of the sphere has tangents $AF,AG$. Let $AF,AG$ touch the circle at $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Let $s$ be the edge length of the pyramid (they are all the same). Because $AF=AG$ is the altitude of an equilateral triangle with side length $s$, so $AF=AG=\frac12s\sqrt3$. Also let $P$ be the mid-point of $FG$, so $FP=\frac12s$.

Let the centre of the sphere (and thus the circle) be $O$. Consider that $\sin\angle XAO=\sin\angle PAF=\frac{FP}{FA}=\frac13\sqrt3$. So by the law of sines,

$$AO=\frac{\sin\angle AXO\cdot XO}{\sin\angle XAO}=\frac{\sin90^0\cdot XO}{\frac13\sqrt3}=\frac1{\frac13\sqrt3}=\sqrt3\text.$$

Therefore, the distance from the centre of the sphere to the apex of the pyramid is $\sqrt3$.

Comment: I think the OP wanted the distance from the 'apex' of the pyramid. Isn't the apex defined as "the top or highest part of something, especially one forming a point"?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Which is $A$. The distance is $AO$. The pyramid is seen "upside down".

Comment: If you recall it is an _inverted_ pyramid. $A$ is the _lowest_ point of the pyramid, so it can not be the apex. And you made some assumptions not necessarily true: for example, how do you know that the sphere is a tangent to all $5$ planes?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I didn't assume it to be tangent to the $5$ planes. But it _is_ tangent to $4$ planes (not including the base). That's because the triangles are equilateral, so the base $BCDE$ is a square, so it's symmetric along the plane containing $AFG$ and the plane containing $A$ and the other median of $BCDE$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan If the OP wanted the distance from the _highest_ point, there's not enough information.

Comment: Which is precisely why others like me refrained from answering. I think the OP is inactive so we may have to wait for sometime.

Comment: AFG is not equilateral.  ACD is equilateral, and $FG = CD$ and $AF$ is smaller than $AC$